# Custom meta box for news ticker in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, news-ticker

I want to show a meta box in my wordpress project which I made by installing smart mag theme.It shows a news ticker on top of the page.When I post any news, the news go in the news ticker.But I want only selective news to be in the home page which I can control using meta box which has two options :YES or NO. If I press YES, that post title will be in news ticker else otherwise. The code in my theme is as following:-

```
<div class="trending-ticker">
                    <span class="heading"><?php echo Bunyad::options()->topbar_ticker_text; // filtered html allowed for admins ?></span>

                    <ul>
                        <?php $query = new WP_Query(apply_filters('bunyad_ticker_query_args', array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'desc', 'posts_per_page' => 8))); ?>

                        <?php while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>

                            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I do this? Please help